# How to convert intensity arbitray units to percentage in a XRD data?

Tags: data-analysis, unit-conversion, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography, data

In  powder x ray diffraction result contains mainly two values 2theta and intensity where 2theta is in degree's and intensity is in arbitrary unit
[image]

```
 2theta intensity
    5,    39
    5.01, 33
    5.02, 27
    5.03, 29
    5.04, 22
    5.05, 35
    5.06, 26
    5.07, 26
    5.08, 35
    5.09, 31
    5.1, 42
    5.11, 47
    5.12, 44
    5.13, 30
    5.14, 27
    5.15, 34
    5.16, 29
    5.17, 31
    5.18, 40
    5.19, 32
    5.2, 43
    5.21, 39
    5.22, 32
```

But when we compare this data with jcpds database 2theta have the same degree metric but intensity is in percentage. The highest intensity peak have the highest value(100%) and the lowest intensity peak have the lowest intensity percentage. If I have a raw xrd data then how should I convert my peaks arbitray unit intensity to percentage? what is the formula used for calculating percentage of intensity?

Comment: You want to multiply all of the intensity terms by 100/max, where max is the maximum intensity value in your dataset.

Comment: @lemon thanks I was looking for that only. If you rewrite this comment as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have a raw xrd data then how should I convert my peaks arbitray unit intensity to percentage?

In  olden days  visual intensity scale was used by us in the interpretation of single crystal  diffraction data.

As the relative intensities were a requirement the laboratory standards were set on the 'reference' diffraction photographs available say of Laue spots or  rotation /oscillation photographs.

In modern times XRD diffractometers data show intensity of the peaks by number of photon counts at different angular positions.

Usually The raw intensity data is measured in counts, corresponding roughly to individual diffraction events.

This  data  is  dependent on the source, the detector, the instrumental design, sample preparation and a host of other factors and so is not useful in itself. So It is common to normalise by the intensity of the largest peak, so that comparisons may be made between measurements collected under different conditions.

In cases where Intensity data is used to measure presence of  specific  material or phases in a sample -For example in mineral  analysis by Powder diffraction pattern /or liquid  sample

*the ratio of the standard count/intensity and the measured value is taken in calculation.*

For more quantitative calculations, it is also possible to include a **reference material** and scale the intensity by that of one of its peaks.

**Profile fitting** is the most precise way to determine diffraction peak 
position, intensity, and width for calculating lattice parameters and 
crystallite size.

**Rietveld   Refinement:**

The Rietveld  method is used to refine the crystal structure model of a 
material.  It can be used for quantitative phase ID, lattice parameter and 
crystallite size calculations, and determine atom positions and 
occupancies

One can see details :

> http://prism.mit.edu/xray/oldsite/Basics%20of%20X-Ray%20Powder%20Diffraction.pdf